# How to print string C++ mfc

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I created project using VS2008 wizard SDI > CView
How can i print some text from Cstring to my main window CView

for example in dialog window with list box i use smth like this m_ListBox1.AddString((LPCTSTR)s);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print it in the view (without any controls or anything like that), you can use something like `pDC->Textout()` or `pDC->DrawText()` inside your view class' `OnDraw()` function. Note that by default the `pDC` parameter has its name commented out -- you'll need to un-comment it before you can use it.